# How to split text using numbers as a delimiter in Google Sheets using a formula

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

I know how to split text using other delimiters such as a comma, equal sign etc. I am having trouble for examples that require a number delimiter.

A typical split formula that uses a comma delimiter would look like this:

```
=SPLIT(A1, ",")
```

I am struggling with splitting text that looks something like this. The delimiter here is a number.

```
This is a random text of 20 characters but could be 30 characters as well.
```

Output should be

```
This is a random text of | 20 | characters but could be | 30 | characters as well.
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\d+","|$0|"),"|")
```

Maybe better, to remove spaces:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s*(\d+)\s*","|$1|"),"|")
```